# mailboxer - get recipient of a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailboxer

I can get the last **sender** of a message:

> > conversation.receipts_for(current_user).last.message.sender.name

but cannot get the **recipient(s)** of that same message.  I would like to display gmail-esk:

Sender name, Recipient name | Subject | Date

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this method in a helper file:

```
  def participant_names(conversation)
    conversation.receipts.reject { |p| p.receiver == current_user }.collect {|p| p.receiver.name }.uniq.join(" ,")
  end
```

What this is doing is, removing the current_user from the conversation object, then creates a new array that contains the names for (in this case users) that conversation object. the '.uniq' method ensures that each users name is only displayed once (in the case there have been many message back and forth conversation). Finally comma separates them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `participants` method with mailboxer, but I believe there is no recipient(s). Instead, I created this:

```
recipient = conversation.participants.find { |p| p != current_user }
```

Note that `current_user` comes from devise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That only seems to give me one recipient of my message. If I send a message to userA, userB and userC. I want to see all of the users that I sent that message to within the conversation thread...

Comment: In that case, replace 'find' with 'select'.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same with the exception that it's now pulling back an array. It's odd since the doc states that the participants method "Returns an array of participants". I would take that as a array of participants of the conversation

Comment: You should be getting back an array of user objects, that's the intended result of the method. From each of the user objects, you can get name, etc... What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to sent a conversation to many users and then, when I view the conversation `conversation=mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])`, I want to see all of the participants that were included in that conversation (excluding myself of course!)